# Relative path for properties file

Tags: java, properties, path, relative-path

I'm using a properties file:

```
try 
{
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties"));
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
}
```

Where should I place `filename.properties`? I don't want to specify absolute path as this code has to work in different platforms. I tried to place it in the same directory as de class but it doesn't work.  (Sorry if it's a stupid question)

Maybe I can get the path where the current class is placed somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

be sure that your property file is available to your compiled (.class) file and get it this way

```
getClass().getResource("filename.properties") // you get an URL, then openStream it
```

or

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties") // you get an InputStream
```

Example:

```
import java.net.URL;
public class SampleLoad {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final URL resource = SampleLoad.class.getResource("SampleLoad.class");
        System.out.println(resource);
    }
}
```

this main retrieves its own compiled version at runtime:

> file:/C:/_projects/toolbox/target/classes/org/game/toolbox/SampleLoad.class

Comment: Ok it works, but I have to remove 'file:/' from that path, so I have to replace "new FileInputStream(filename.properties)" in my code with: `FileInputStream(resource.toString().substring("file:/".length(),resource.toString().length())));`
`

Comment: @de3, use @Guillaume's second form, `getResourceAsStream(*)`.  It will continue to work even if you ship your classes in a jar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :
String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");